# Ubuntu showing 2 desktops/screens

Tags: screen, 14.04

After installing Ubuntu 14.04.2, I noticed the mouse disappears from the screen  when I move it far to the riht side but after moving it back it comes back to the screen.

When I tried to run Eclpise for the first time on this new laptop I had encountered a problem so I took a **screenshot** of it and then I guess that I have 2 screens:

[image]

**Note that I see only the desktop on the left.**

How can I get rid of this situation ?

Comment: Is there a HDMI-cable plugged in?

Comment: yes, but the mouse has the same behavior without it

Comment: Try the following:

    sudo apt-get remove 3.2.0-64
    sudo update-grub
    sudo reboot

Comment: Excuse me, i thought you were running Ubuntu on a VMWare.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open display settings and if there is another screen disable it.